# APScheduler - running multiple jobs at the same time

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

In APScheduler [docs](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html#limiting-the-number-of-concurrently-executing-instances-of-a-job) is:

> By default, only one instance of each job is allowed to be run at the same time. This means that if the job is about to be run but the previous run hasn’t finished yet, then the latest run is considered a misfire. It is possible to set the maximum number of instances for a particular job that the scheduler will let run concurrently, by using the `max_instances` keyword argument when adding the job.

So if I have:

```
def test_func(name):
    print('Hello, ' + name)


from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

scheduler.add_job(test_func, 'date', run_date=date(2021, 12, 24), args=['John'])
scheduler.add_job(test_func, 'date', run_date=date(2021, 12, 24), args=['Mary'])
scheduler.add_job(test_func, 'date', run_date=date(2021, 12, 24), args=['Jack'])
```

Will `test_func` be run only once or three times?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all different schedules (jobs in APScheduler 3 lingo), so they will all run concurrently.

Comment: Is there a way to not run theses functions at the same time concurrently even when they are schedule to run at the same time?

Comment: Make a function that makes all these calls manually, and schedule that instead.